# Finding Cartesian coordinates of remaining vertices of triangle, given a vertex and angle from y-axis

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have an isosceles triangle $ABC$, where the height $h$ and angle at vertex $A$ are known. The Cartesian coordinates of vertex $A$ are also known to be $\left(x,y\right)$.

If the angle between the y-axis and the line represented by $h$ is $θ$, is it possible to find the Cartesian coordinates of points $B$ and $C$?

[image: illustration of the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.

The angle between the $y$-axis and $AB$ is $\theta - \tfrac{A}{2}$, and the angle between the $y$-axis and $AC$ is $\theta + \tfrac{A}{2}$.
So you will get
\begin{align*}
B &= (x - r \sin(\theta - \tfrac{A}{2}), y + r \cos(\theta - \tfrac{A}{2}) \\
C &= (x - r \sin(\theta + \tfrac{A}{2}), y + r \cos(\theta + \tfrac{A}{2})
\end{align*}
where $r = AB = AC = \frac{h}{\cos(\tfrac{A}{2})}$.

Comment: Brilliant, this appears to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It is not. You don't have enough information. You could easily construct a different isosceles triangle with the same coordinates for $A$, the same value for $h$ and $\theta$.

EDIT: Now that you've edited your question by making it clear that you know the internal angle at vertex $A$, you have enough information to uniquely identify the coordinates of the remaining points, as per Goos' answer.

Comment: But if I know that the angle at A is, say, 60°, and can solve for length BC, does that give enough information?

Comment: @user153938 What do you mean by angle at $A$?

Comment: I may have labeled the illustration in a confusing manner. So, ignoring the Cartesian aspect for now, say that I have the isosceles triangle _ABC_ with height _h_, and angle _A_ is known. From this, I can solve for _BC_, no? If I then know that the angle between the y-axis and the line _h_ is θ, can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough information.  With what you've given, $B$ and $C$ can be any points equidistant from $A$ that are both on the line defined by $B$ and $C$.