# Calculate the coordinates of two points in an isosceles triangle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

In the triangle below, given the point A, angle θ and length d of the two equal sides, how can the points B and C be calculated?

[image: Isosceles triangle]

Edit:After brainstorming for quite some time, I ended up with a complicated system that looks like that

$(x_1-x)^2+(y_1-y)^2=d^2$

$(x_2-x)^2+(y_2-y)^2=d^2$

$(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2=BC^2$

where

$BC^2=2d^2(1-cos\theta)$ (from the law of cosines)

Three equations, four unknowns. Unsolvable!

Update : I found the closest thing to a solution here : [Finding Cartesian coordinates of remaining vertices of triangle, given a vertex and angle from y-axis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1101779/finding-cartesian-coordinates-of-remaining-vertices-of-triangle-given-a-vertex) but I'm missing the angle θ (angle between the height h of the triangle and the y axis)

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this question?

Comment: If both accounts [Geysser](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/326859/geysser) and [Geysser Sdz](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/326861/geysser-sdz) belong to you should probably [merge them](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/merge-accounts/info) to have better access to your question. In particular, so that you can edit your question directly and not using [suggested edits](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/601856).

Comment: Do we have to assume that the triangle is symmetric with respect to the line $y=x$? Because, without that assumption, there are infinitely many solutions (all of them being on the circle of centre $A$ and radius $d$).

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: I'd be happy to help you in real time for free (see my contact info), but I will expect you to learn, and won't just give you the answers.